# PHP Array key exist

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working with an API and now i want to check if an array key exists then do something.

With an array i gather data like this:

```
$pers_payload = array(
    'gender' => 'Unknown', //or Male / Female
    'first_name' => $_POST['billing_first_name'],
    'family_name'   => $_POST ['billing_last_name'],
    'email' => $_POST['billing_email'],
    'linked_as_contact_to_organization' => array(
        array(
            'organization_id' => $organization_id, // add the person as a contact to the newly created organization
            'work_email' => $_POST['billing_email'],
            'work_phone' => $_POST['billing_phone']
            )
        ),
    'visiting_address' => array(
        'country_code'          =>  'NL'
        ), // can be extented with other address data
    'postal_address' => array(
        'country_code'      =>  $_POST['billing_country'] 
    )   // can be extented with other address data
);
```

Then i use a get request like this:

```
$tet = $SimplicateApi->makeApiCall('GET','/crm/person?q[first_name]=Kevin');
```

And then i check if the array exists inside the results of the get request like this:

```
if(array_key_exists('first_name', $tet)) {
   // do Nothing
}else{
   // make API call
   $person = $SimplicateApi->makeApiCall('POST','/crm/person',json_encode($pers_payload));
}
```

Im sure the get request is working, because i did a var_dump($tet); and i got this result:

```
  array(3) { ["data"]=> array(6) { [0]=> array(18) { ["id"]=> string(39) "person:71cf33fb785433ab66550e5701120079
```

Well thats part of what i got, i cant post all of it. because it contains sensitive information.

For some reason even if the array_key exists this code still runs:

```
$person = $SimplicateApi->makeApiCall('POST','/crm/person',json_encode($pers_payload));
```

--

```
array(3) { ["value"]=> bool(false) ["id"]=> string(41) "interest:7d3458131ea89afbe1bb3149bee8b668" ["name"]=> string(3) "Web" } } } } ["gender"]=> string(7) "Unknown" ["first_name"]=> string(5) "Kevin" ["family_name"]=> string(7) "A" ["full_name"]=> string(13) "Kevin A" ["email"]=> string(24) "ma@edd-marketingsuppxort.nl" ["phone"]=> string(8) "06269684" } [5]=> array(11) { ["id"]=> string(39) "person:51045f230a9cc39136aaf3a22a069eb0" ["interests"]=> array(1) { [0]=>
```

Comment: But your var_dump($tet) doesn't have "first_name" key?

Comment: It does @L.Herrera i just didn't want to post it. I just posted part of the results.

Comment: Try   if(array_key_exists('first_name', $tet['data'][0])). If not working, replace your actual values inside $tet with dummy values and post it here

Comment: @Ima still posts it eventho the first name i enter exists

Comment: Why don't you try `if(!empty($tet['first_name'])) {...}`?

Comment: Then replace your actual values inside $tet with dummy values and post it here. I want to know the actual position of your first_name

Comment: @Ima if(array_key_exists('first_name', $tet['Kevin'][0]))  still posts the data and Kevin exists

Comment: what is the output of var_dump($tet['Kevin'][0]['first_name']) ?

Comment: @Ima no output. But i added a lil more of the var_dump($tet); to my answer

Comment: First thing you should understand is working of array_key_exists.http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Comment: array_key_exists will not check for the the key in the child array. It will search in the key of the parent array only

Comment: Is there a way to actually do what i want @Ima

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129353/discussion-between-ima-and-kevin-a).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are the first array keys of $tet?
We can see the first one is data, but what about the others one?

```
if(array_key_exists('first_name', $tet['data'])) {
  //code...
}
```

edit: as @lma says array_key_exists can not dig into child, and even the edited structure you gave us look weird, some trailing } in the middle of the array.

Comment: Please do not post on the answer section if its not meant to be an answer.

Comment: You can remove it.

Comment: Do you know how to do what i want, im having trouble finding out.

Comment: as I say, there is something weird with the data you have sended we need the full structure of your array, just mask the sensitive data